# Moose - Determine if Lazy Attribute has been set

Tags: perl, moose

I'm trying to figure out a way to see if one of my lazily built attributes has been set or not.  I've scoured the docs for both **Moose::Meta::Attribute** and and **Class::MOP::Attribute**, and saw the `get_value` and `has_value` methods, but they don't seem to be working for me.

The documentation for `get_value` says:

```
$attr->has_value($instance)
```

But what is $instance?  I tried using my object, but that just returns the error:

> "You must pass a package name and it cannot be blessed.."

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `$instance` should be your object. It's hard to know what you're doing wrong without seeing more code.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  Using my object as $instance actually DID work, it was just returning true 100% of the time. But that appears to be a different problem, so I'll ask it in a different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you probably want is a predicate on your attribute. E.g.

```
has foo => (
  is        => 'rw',
  lazy      => 1,
  predicate => 'has_foo',
);
```

Comment: This is for my DB interaction code, so I was hoping for a little more of a catch-all (setting a predicate for every single lazy attribute is unfortunate...) But since this is the best answer to the question I ASKED, I thank you and will accept it.

Comment: You may want to look at MooseX::AttributeShortcuts then, specifically the 'is => "rwp"', 'is => "lazy"', and 'predicate => 1' options...  YMMV.